# Regex replacement in Spyder's editor not working as Notepad++ with the capture group syntax

Tags: regex, spyder

I am using Spyder v3.3.3 editor with Python 3.7.1 in Anaconda for Regex replacement, and the Spyder regex engine is not giving the expected behavior.  Instead of naming capture groups with $1, $2, $2, ... $n, I am forced to use \1, \2, \3, ...\n, so this means I have to change my regex syntax that I use in Notepad++ to .

```
For example: 
    print "this is a string", anExpression, anObject
    print "Market Cap:",self.marketCap
    print "Website: https://www.google.com/finance?q=" + self.
```

In the Spyder Editor, the following regex replacements do not work.
FIND:           (print)\s(.+)
REPLACE WITH:   $1($2)

This substitutes "$1($2" for what's in the brackets [ print "this is a string", anExpression, anObject ]

If I use the following regex replacement then I get the correct result.
REPLACE WITH:   \1(\2)

The differences between Notepad++ and Spyder are substantial, to the point where my Notepad++ regex snippet library doesn't work.

Is there an easy way to substitute a different regex engine into Spyder?

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You asked

> Is there an easy way to substitute a different regex engine into Spyder?

My answer: No, this is not possible, sorry.